# AlCl3(aq) reaction with NaHCO₃ to form alumina Al2O3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In a demonstration, aluminum foil was add to a solution of $\ce{HCl}$ and allowed to react, the reaction was presented as

$\ce{2Al(s) + 6HCl(aq) -> 2Al­Cl3(aq) + 3H2(g)↑}$

After filtration, the solution appeared optically clear.

Next, baking soda, i.e. sodium carbonate $\ce{NaHCO3(s)}$, was added, and the solution then turned whitish opaque. After a while a white precipitation could be observed. In the presentation it was claimed that alumina, $\ce{Al2O3(s)}$, was precipitating out of the solution.

What reaction takes place when $\ce{NaHCO3(s)}$ is added to the solution? Is it correct to claim that $\ce{AlCl3(aq)}$ exists in the solution?

Comment: 1) Aluminum cation is an acid in water solution.  2) Acids react with bicarbonates to release carbon dioxide.

Comment: $\ce{Al^{3+} + 3 HCO3^- -> Al(OH)3  +  3 CO2 }$ then $\ce{2Al(OH)3 -> Al2O3 + 3 H2O}$

Comment: $\ce{AlCl3}$ does not really exist in solution. it is dissociated into ions $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$, which are themselves hydrated

Comment: In the reaction formula written by @Maurice it looks like Al(OH)3 is an intermediate. Would it be possible to control the reaction and stop it at this stage, i.e. before any Al2O3 precipitates.

Comment: $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ and $\ce{Al2O3}$ are both precipitates, and they are both hydrated. I don't know whether it is possible to distinguish between them.